# Screen recorder for tracking back your steps while debugging?

Tags: debugging, screenshot

I am wondering whether there is a screen recorder that is usable for checking what exactly you did a couple of minutes ago while debugging, or just checking what value for a variable was displayed the last time you hit that breakpoint etc. (Of course this latter question would be something terrific for an IDE to implement, but I've never seen something like that so far. :-)

For this you would need a screen recorder that could record all day and preferably automatically delete the recording the recording that is, say, older than an hour. Probably the recording format should be something that is good for screen recording instead of natural scenes.

Do you know a screen recorder like that or at least one that comes close?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know any screen recorder designed specifically for this purpose.

However FRAPS can be used to capture screen. I would suggest you use a low framerate and a low resolution to save disk space.
[Click here](http://www.fraps.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the money or the access via other means (like MSDN AA), visual studio 2010 ultimate's debugging and unit testing framework includes an error logging with screen capture(video or stills) system, as well as some other fancy things, such as automated retesting with video capture for reviewing.